# Excel VBA Populate Listbox1 based on Listbox2 Selection

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to figure out the proper code for populating a listbox based on a selection from a second listbox. I will explain my question the best I can. I have one worksheet with two columns populated like this.

```
(COLUMN A)    (COLUMN B)
PART NUMBER:  LOCATION:
PART A        LOC1,LOC7,LOC12,LOC21
PART B        LOC2,LOC8,LOC13,LOC22
PART C        LOC6,LOC9,LOC18,LOC20
```

I want to be able to populate ListBox1 with the "PART NUMBER" column and when I click on "PART A" I get just a list of items for location from (Column B) in ListBox2. I hope this makes sense and someone can help me out. Thank you in advance.

To populate my ListBox:

```
Dim rngName As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet2")
For i = 1 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row Step 1
If ws.Cells(i, 1).Value <> vbNullString Then Me.LstPartNum.AddItem    ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
Next i
```

To Test populate and split by commas:

```
UserForm1.LstPartNum.List = Split("LOC1,LOC7,LOC12,LOC21", ",")
```

Comment: Do you know how to use VBA? If yes, please show what you have tried so far, and where that attempt has failed. If you do not know how to use VBA, I don't recommend you do that. There are non-VBA solutions available here, using the Data Validation tool in the Data ribbon, and the Name Manager. Try this explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14997530/5090027

Comment: Yes, I do know some VBA. I have not yet done what I am trying to do. I have edited my initial question to show what I am doing. I just cannot figure out how to make them interact with each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the change event of the part number combobox do something like this.

```
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet2")
lRow = 1

'Loop through the rows
Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.count
    'Check if Column A has the value of the selected part number.
    If ws.Range("A" & lRow).Value = LstPartNum.Text Then
        UserForm1.LstLocation.Clear
        'Load the locations
        UserForm1.LstLocation.List = Split(ws.Range("B" & lRow).Value, ",")
        Exit Do
    End If
lRow = lRow + 1
Loop
```

If your UserForm1.LstPartNum.List = Split() does not work to load the list, here  is code to loop the split array.

```
Dim szLocs() As String
Dim i as integer

szLocs= Split(ws.Range("B" & lRow).Value, ",")

i = 0
'Loop though each token
Do While i <= UBound(szPieces)
    UserForm1.LstPartNum.Additem szPieces(i)
i = i + 1
Loop
```

Comment: MatthewD... thanks for the help. I am getting a "Type Mismatch" error on the IF statement line. My PartNumber listbox is loading ok, but when I click on a part number in that list I get the error. I am using the change event to trigger your code.  I am assuming that the line "Userform1" should reference my Location listbox, correct?  Thanks

Comment: @user3340949  That was my bad.  Switching between C and VB made me do it.  That line should have an & not a plus.  I also added an exit do to  the above to help with performance.  And yes your assumption oubout the Userform1 was correct. Whatever your form is called put it there.

Comment: You probably don't even need to reference the form. You can probalby just refer to it as LstPartNum.List  I just carried that over from your code.

Comment: I also added a LstLocation.Clear

Comment: MatthewD Thank You VERY much for your time and help. This works EXACTLY as I had hoped it would.