# VBA - populate ListBox from multiple ListObjects

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, listobject

I am trying to populate a ListBox with entries from multiple ListObjects.
But not all entries should be populated, only those which have a specific value in a column of the ListObject.

Example:
ListObjects consist of 3 columns: [Name], [Size], [Position]

All entries from ListObject1 to ListObject5 should be populated into the ListBox if the value in column [Position] is "Top".

Next question based on that result:
How can I then in a second ListBox display all entries of the depended ListObject where [Position] is not "Top".
In other words, not all entries which are not "Top" from all ListObjects should be displayed in the second LIstBox, only those possible entries from the specific ListObject where the value picked in the first ListBox matches.

My thoughts where maybe strange, but what about creating a whole new table (maybe an Array), which consists of all entries from all ListObjects which will be generated when opening the UserForm and then add a third column to it - [ListObjectNumber] - which consists of the information from which Table this information is coming from, that would help the second ListBox to only display the right entries... but maybe this is too far ahead.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a spreadsheet laid out as such:

- Formatted via the Home tab with "Format as Table"; this creates ListObjects
  named automatically as "Table1", "Table2", "Table3", "Table4", "Table5"
- Sheet named "listbox" for example
- ActiveX command button added to show the user form named frmListbox in this example:

  ```
  Sub Button2_Click()
      frmListbox.Show
  End Sub
  ```

[image]

```
    Private Sub cmdPopulate_Click()
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim table As ListObject
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim i As Long, j As Long, criteriaRow As Long, lastCol As Long
        Dim myarray() As String

        With Me.lbUsed

            'Set relevant sheetname (or create loop for worksheets)
            Set ws = Sheets("listbox")

            criteriaRow = -1
            For Each table In ws.ListObjects
                'Set relevant range/table
                'Remember: top row are headings
                Set rng = ws.Range(table)

                'Remember: last colum not displayed in listbox (-1) for this example
                lastCol = rng.Columns.Count - 1

                .Clear
                .ColumnHeads = False
                .ColumnCount = lastCol

                'Remember: leave out row 0; column headings
                For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
                    If (rng.Cells(i, 3) = "Top") Then
                        criteriaRow = criteriaRow + 1
                        'Columns go in first demension so that rows can resize as needed
                        ReDim Preserve myarray(lastCol, criteriaRow)
                        For j = 0 To lastCol
                            myarray(j, criteriaRow) = rng.Cells(i, j + 1)
                        Next    'Column in table
                    End If
                Next    'Row in table
            Next    'Table (ListObject)

            'Place array in natural order to display in listbox
            .List = TransposeArray(myarray)

            'Set the widths of the column, separated with a semicolon
            .ColumnWidths = "100;75"
            .TopIndex = 0
        End With
    End Sub

    Public Function TransposeArray(myarray As Variant) As Variant
        Dim X As Long
        Dim Y As Long
        Dim Xupper As Long
        Dim Yupper As Long
        Dim tempArray As Variant

        Xupper = UBound(myarray, 2)
        Yupper = UBound(myarray, 1)
        ReDim tempArray(Xupper, Yupper)
        For X = 0 To Xupper
            For Y = 0 To Yupper
                tempArray(X, Y) = myarray(Y, X)
            Next Y
        Next X
        TransposeArray = tempArray
    End Function
```

---

For the 2nd question:

The code sample below shows how when clicking on an item in a list called lstDisorder populates the next list box called lstTreatment with the values from named ranges on the spreadsheet.

```
Private Sub lstDisorder_Click()
Dim x As Integer

x = lstDisorder.ListIndex
Select Case x
    Case Is = 0
        lstTreatment.RowSource = "Depression"
    Case Is = 1
        lstTreatment.RowSource = "Anxiety"
    Case Is = 2
        lstTreatment.RowSource = "OCD"
    Case Is = 3
        lstTreatment.RowSource = "Stubstance"
    End Select
End Sub
```

Here is another approach:

```
Private Sub lstTeam_Click()

    Dim colUniqueItems      As New Collection
    Dim vItem               As Variant
    Dim rFound              As Range
    Dim FirstAddress        As String

    'First listBox
    Me.lstItems.Clear

    'populate first listBox from range on worksheet
    With Worksheets("Team").Range("A2:A" & (Cells(1000, 1).End(xlUp).row))
        'Find what was clicked in first listBox
        Set rFound = .Find(what:=lstTeam.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        'If something is selected, populate second listBox
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            'Get the address of selected item in first listBox
            FirstAddress = rFound.Address
            On Error Resume Next
            Do
                'Add the value of the cell to the right of the cell selected in first listBox to the collection
                colUniqueItems.Add rFound.Offset(, 1).Value, CStr(rFound.Offset(, 1).Value)
                'Find the next match in the range of the first listBox
                Set rFound = .FindNext(rFound)
            'Keep looking through the range until there are no more matches
            Loop While rFound.Address <> FirstAddress
            On Error GoTo 0
            'For each item found and stored in the collection
            For Each vItem In colUniqueItems
                'Add it to the next listBox
                Me.lstItems.AddItem vItem
            Next vItem
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Here's a good resource on listBox which shows how to [populate ListBox from an Array](https://analysistabs.com/vba-code/excel-userform/listbox/) and how to Get Selected Items from ListBox1 to ListBox2 and more.

Comment: Thank you very much! Works pretty well and I am greatful for your comments! helped a lot. (sorry for the delay, was on vacation)

Comment: and what about the second part of my question, regarding the other Listbox showing all other positions, being not "Top" and related to the specific ListObject? Thank you very much.

Comment: Create a second array and add the else portion of the if to collect the records that <> "Top". Outside the with section, create another with for a second ListBox on the form to populate with the 2nd array's data.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but this will populate all postions from all ListObjects <> "Top".
What I want is a listing in the 2nd listbox with only the positions <> "Top", from the specific ListObject - the ListObject is the source ListObject of the selected position of the first listbox in the userform.

Comment: Then in the else portion, prior to collecting the data for the 2nd array, add another if to test if the ListObject is the one you want to collect this data from. The logic would go something like: If table.name = "theTableNameIWant" then collect data in 2nd array.

Comment: the script you provided cannot know what the user will choose in the first listbox. the data in the second listbox should come from the specific listobject, depended on the position chosen in the first listbox. must i create a fourth column to each listobject, and fill the table.name to it? then for the second listbox i could take this information as well as <> 'top' loop through all listobjects again to retrieve the data? but this is not really efficient and looks strange in the tables within excel somehow...

Comment: Oh, that was not clear in your original question. I suggest you open a new question for your second question so that you may get an answer faster than I may be able to get to it for you. May I suggest you "draw a picture" to step through the logic you want so that it may be coded with less confusion. "create a fourth column to each listobject, and fill the table.name to it" you could do that. In the code so far there are only 2 columns in the table. You could add a 3 for the origination of the ListObject.name and set the column width here .ColumnWidths = "100;75;0" so it's hidden.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49754501/cannot-copy-to-the-last-cell-in-the-range/49755231#49755231 where it shows how to query data and then you could build the listObject off of the output as another way to go.

Comment: You can also put the code to build the next listBox in the prior listBox change or click events. See some of these references: a) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39170771/listbox-generates-secondary-listbox-based-on-selection  b) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-mT54td4lSY  c) https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/796702-populate-2nd-listbox-based-1st-listbox-selection-unique-items-only.html  d) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31542647/excel-vba-populate-listbox1-based-on-listbox2-selection

Comment: The second answer shows how you could populate a listBox via an on click event from another listBox. In your code per our discussion you could add  ListBox2.AddItem; such as:  If table.name = "theTableNameIWant" then ListBox2.AddItem.